# An error occurred while installing fatrat, please help

Tags: 16.04

I got these error when trying installing fatrat:

```
ignoring file '50unattended-upgrade.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/'**  
E: Unable to locate package fatrat
```

Comment: How do you install fatrat ? Using ppa or... ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the file should solve the problem, and may get rid of all the notices if the directory one is simply occurring because there are invalid files within it. Thus `50unattended-upgrades` file should be removed.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist
```

For fatrat installation, run following command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libgloox-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libpion-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5svg5-private-dev libboost-date-time1.58-dev qttools5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools libtorrent-rasterbar-dev cmake git
git clone https://github.com/LubosD/fatrat.git
cd fatrat
cmake . -DWITH_BITTORRENT=ON -DWITH_SFTP=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make
sudo make install
fatrat
```

The prefix can be changed to `/usr` using `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr`. The default prefix is `/usr/local`,
but may be implementation dependent.

http://fatrat.dolezel.info/download